# Check that an object is instanceof angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

### HTML:

```
<div id="obj"></div>
```

#### in jQuery:

```
var obj = $('#obj');
obj instanceof jQuery;
'true'
```

So, I assumed that

```
angular.module('app', []) instanceof angular.module()
```

to be true..
Instead I get:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$injector/nomod?p0=undefined

... ok so try:

```
app instanceof angular.module   
false 


app.isPrototypeOf(angular.module)
false

app.isPrototypeOf(angular)
false
```

What am I missing here? How do I check that an object is an instance of angular?

#### Other  confusing things:

```
typeof angular
"object"
typeof app
"object"
app instanceof angular
```

TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #

^^ if angular is an object and app is an object, why is it expecting a function?

```
Object.keys(app);

//returns 

_configBlocks: Array[0]
_invokeQueue: Array[0]
_runBlocks: Array[0]
animation: function (){f[e||
config: function (){f[e||
constant: function (){f[e||
controller: function (){f[e||
directive: function (){f[e||
factory: function (){f[e||
filter: function (){f[e||
name: "app"
provider: function (){f[e||
requires: Array[0]
run: function (a){n.push(a);return this}
service: function (){f[e||
value: function (){f[e||
__proto__: Object
```

^^ where is the .prototype? How can I determine that an object is an instance of an angular object?

Comment: The question is: why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @Blackhole That's not a relevant question; it can be done with every other library / framework I've encountered.

Comment: That being said @Blackhole the reason why i need it in this instance is to test whether angular is being used on a page. The reason i said that your question is irrelevant is because i don't want people to focus on whether my implementation / instance of this question is valid; the focus needs to be on whether or not it's possible and how to do it.

Comment: An angular module is a plain old object ([see the definition](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/loader.js#L111)). Just check that your variable has the appropriate keys (`provider`, `factory`, `service`, …).

Comment: so far that's the best answer I've gotten if you want the points